# What's the least painful way to get Make onto my Mac?

Tags: macos, makefile

I don't want to install 2.6 gigs worth of XCode just to have Make on my system (also, I'm not even sure where my Mac install disks are).

Is there a less cumbersome way to get Make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have split Xcode into smaller packages now... you can get the nix devtools now as a separate install. The package is called "**Command Line Tools for XCode**":

> This package enables UNIX-style development via Terminal by installing command line developer tools, as well as Mac OS X SDK frameworks and headers. Many useful tools are included, such as the Apple LLVM compiler, linker, and Make. If you use Xcode, these tools are also embedded within the Xcode IDE, and can be installed on your system using the Downloads preferences pane within Xcode 4.3 and later. This package requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later.

Comment: You need to log in to the developer site with your appleid (set one up if you dont have one - its free) and then go to the downloads area. Youll see it in the list.